# Not able to add AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions to service collection

Tags: masstransit

Not able to add AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions to service collection(it says AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions not in iservice collection), I have installed nuget packages Masstransit and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

I need the exact namespace and solution

Comment: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction